# Cannot use positional argument after named argument | Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, arguments

I'm in the Yii2 PHP Framework course, and I have one problem. I'm not similar with the PHP very well, so it's hard to me to solve that problem.

So, I'm trying to make the "Delete" button in my web, and I'm receiving error: "Cannot use positional argument after named argument".

There is the fragment of code:

```
'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
'buttons' => [
    'delete' => function ($url) {
        return Html::a(text:'Delete', $url, [
            'data-method' => 'post'
        ]);
    }
]
```

Comment: Get rid of the name `text:`

Comment: is that a typo or the actual code `text:'Delete'` ?

Answer (score 4):

This is not a Yii2 problem, this behavior is expected and documented, if you check the [php documentation pages](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.named-arguments) it talks about this case, it says:

> Named arguments can be combined with positional arguments. In this case, the named arguments must come after the positional arguments. It is also possible to specify only some of the optional arguments of a function, regardless of their order.

Which makes sense, if PHP let you place named arguments first, then positional, it would be impossible to determine what parameters should be matched with the *unnamed* arguments you are actually passing.

On the opposite situation, first positional arguments get matched one to one with the function parameters based on their order, then, named arguments allow you to skip having to give values to parameters when you are happy with their default value but want to assign a value to some other parameter that follows them.

The easiest solution is, like Barmar said in the comments, to remove `text:` and use positional arguments, your arguments are already in the correct order, and you are using all the parameters.

You could also make all your arguments named.

As a side note, I think the error message in this case is self-explanatory and very clear.